# Read JSON with ASP.NET 2.0 VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, json, asp.net-2.0

How can I read JSON with ASP.NET 2.0? Unfortunately we are unable to upgrade the application because of backward compatibility issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/58535) is a good library on codeplex.  It's very easy to use and although the current version is 4.0 there is an older 2.0 version.  I've used the 3.5 version and it worked a treat.

[This page](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) contains some demos and an overview of what to expect.

Comment: Cheers, exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 0):

You can also install ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 extension. it includes classes that provide help with JSON data.